# How to replace the value of a variable field in logstash pipeline

Tags: logstash

For some unavoidable reason, a field "`program`" in my logstash pipeline contains a value like "`date=2023.14.02`". I want to rename the value of this field to "`kernel`". The problem is, the name is variable in nature as a date will be passed to the field every passing day.
I have tried something like this :

```
 if [program]=~/^date.*/ {
    filter {
          mutate {
               rename => {/^date.*/ => "kernel"}
                 }
           }
```

I tried `rename => {"date.*" => "kernel"}`, `rename => {^date.* => "kernel"}` etc.. But it does not work. Is there a correct syntax for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the value of the [program] field with kernel then use `mutate { gsub => [ "program", "^date.*", "kernel" ] }`.

Comment: Thank you, `mutate { gsub => [ "program", "^date.*", "kernel" ] }` did the job.